# Pandas multiindex dataframe selecting data

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given this dataframe below, 
Is there a way to retrieve the columns having **start** values >= 20000 and **stop** values <= 40000?
Where start and stop are the names (not values) of the columns.

[image: Multi-index dataframe]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you can use [`get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.get_level_values.html) + [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.astype.html) to `int` (if necessary), create `mask` with `&` and last select by [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
mask1 = df.columns.get_level_values('start').astype(int) >= 20000
mask2 = df.columns.get_level_values('stop').astype(int) <= 40000

mask = mask1 & mask2
df = df.loc[:, mask]
print (df)
```